# NativeScript UI Chart Legend: change label to square

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular, nativescript-telerik-ui

How do I change the legend label of a pie chart to a square. I looked at the [example code](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/Controls/Angular/Chart/Series/pie) but it does not change the label to a square for me.

```
<RadCartesianChart height="300">
  <CategoricalAxis tkCartesianVerticalAxis></CategoricalAxis>
  <LinearAxis tkCartesianHorizontalAxis></LinearAxis>

  <BarSeries tkCartesianSeries
              [showLabels]="true"
              [items]="sampleData"
              categoryProperty="name"
              valueProperty="value">
    <PointLabelStyle tkBarLabelStyle
                      margin="10"
                      textSize="10"></PointLabelStyle>
  </BarSeries>
</RadCartesianChart>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think such customisation is supported, by default it seems to be square in Android and circle in iOS.

You might have to raise a feature request if you like that option.

Comment: Thanks! I had a feeling that was the case. I will make do with the circles on iOS.